What information can I obtain from power spectrum density (PSD) that I can't obtain from Fourier transform of a signal?
I am interested in understanding what is the benefit of calculating the PSD of a signal. When I apply a Fourier transform on a signal, I obtain the amplitude and the phase of its frequency components. From what i understand, the PSD calculates the power of the frequency components of the signal.
First of all, I would ask (naively) if isn't the power of the frequency components just the amplitude squared? I would guess it's not. What is the difference between the power and the amplitude squared? and more importantly, what information can I gain from calculating the PSD of a signal?
I would like to point out that I am interested in the theoretical aspects of my question and not the practical aspects. I know there are many ways to calculate the PSD but this does not what I am interested in. Let's say I have the Ideal PSD and the Ideal Fourier transform.

this might help!


First of all, I would ask (naively) if isn't the power of the frequency components just the amplitude squared?

This is an extremely good question! And as you guessed, the answer is "not universally".
Taking a step back, especially since you care about the theory:

The PSD is a property of a random process. I.e., the noise at the input of an oscilloscope can have a PSD, even if the observed noise signal is different each time you look.
You can only Fourier-transform things you know. So, you can transform an observation of noise (a so-called realization of the random process), but you cannot Fourier-transform "the noise" (as that has uncountably infinitely many possibilities to look like, and on top of that, goes for infinitely long)


and more importantly, what information can I gain from calculating the PSD of a signal?

So, first step here is realize that "PSD" and "Fourier transform of a signal" simply are two different things: the first you can apply to a random signal, the second you can't.
Now, the question of course is how these two are linked. Because, obviously they are linked: If you do look at, say, what comes out of an RC-low pass filter that is fed with white noise, it's noise, but spectrally shaped (due to the filter). So, it only has a PSD. Sure, you can observe that, and make a Fourier transform of the observation.
Now you think about that and realize that these two things should really better "converge" to the same thing e.g. when you observe for very long, because otherwise, the PSD telling us how much power is in which frequency ranges would be different than the power we observe (via the Fourier transform's magnitude square) in the same regions. And that would mean at least one of them would not describe reality. Huh!
First realization is that if you Fourier transform a very short snippet of noise signal, well, that probably isn't very good at representing the actual power spectrum. Noise is random, there's no guarantee you got a "representative" piece of it in that short time.
So, there's a theorem that links these two: It's the Wiener-Khinchin Theorem.
From that theorem follows that the PSD calculated from the autocorrelation function (so, expectation of (conjugate) product of integrated signal with time-shifted version of itself; a random property) agrees with the expectation of the Fourier transform of realizations of that process, under conditions.
And these conditions include that the random process be wide-sense stationary (WSS). That means it has a finite expectation that's always the same, for every point in time, and that if you find the autocovariance function, it only depends on the time difference, and not on the absolute time you used to compare the random signal to itself.
Sounds a bit complicated, but really mostly implies that the random signal behaves "randomly, but the same randomly" over all times (and you can be stricter than just looking at how it behaves in autocovariance, hence the "wide-sense").
There's random signals where that assumption fails. A classical example is noise where there's no way to define an expectation for a point in time. You can construct such noise – we see that happening quite commonly when one tries to solve a practical issue by dividing one noisy thing by another – where unbounded values are not less likely than 1/their magnitude; then the expectation diverges, and when you can't put a value on an expectation (and $\infty$ is not a value!), then you especially can't say it's a constant. (And in fact, such signals often turn out to not have different methods of deriving a "spectrum" that agree.)
The interesting (because inherent to most real-world signal processing systems) case where that fails are signals whose stochastic properties (especially mean and variance) change with time – for example, the output of a time-varying multipath channel might produce more power at one frequency than at another at some point in time, and then that is the other way around at some other point in time.

Thank you, this seems so well-written!

The power spectral density is useful in determining how the total power is distributed over frequency from a finite length realization of a stationary random process. Realizations of a random signal, modeled as wide-sense stationary, don't have finite energy, and therefore don't possess discrete-time Fourier transforms, since finite energy is a necessary condition for the Fourier integrals to converge. However, these realizations of a random signal have finite average power, and therefore can be characterized by an average power spectral density, abbreviated as PSD.
This is important because, in many applications, signals are such that their future values cannot be known exactly, so we have to resort to probabilistic statements about their true values, and this is no different for spectral analysis. There are two definitions of the power spectral density, which are equivalent under mild assumptions (see Which sample autocovariance sequence estimate should I use for spectral analysis?)
\begin{equation}
\phi(\omega) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}r(k)e^{-j\omega k} = \lim_{N\to\infty}E\left\{\frac{1}{N}\left\lvert\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}y[n]e^{-j\omega n}\right\rvert^{2}\right\}
\end{equation}
Addressing your first question

First of all, I would ask (naively) if isn't the power of the frequency components just the amplitude squared? I would guess it's not. What is the difference between the power and the amplitude squared?

we see from the definition of the PSD that it is not the magnitude squared of the amplitude, but rather the expected value of the amplitude squared. Dropping the expected value gives an estimate known as the periodogram, which is a poor estimator of the PSD (see Why is the sample spectrum considered inconsistent?).
Addressing the second question

and more importantly, what information can I gain from calculating the PSD of a signal?

we obtain an estimate of how the total power is distributed over frequency from a finite length realization of a random process. All PSD estimates contain this information. However, the specific estimator we use determines whether or not we have a probabilistic estimate of the PSD. Classical Fourier methods (i.e. periodogram, correlogram, Welch's, Blackman-Tukey, etc) give a non-parametric estimate of the PSD, and are really quite poor estimators of the PSD (not all non-parametric methods are, just the classical estimators we typically know of). More modern methods of PSD estimation have better statistical properties, or make assumptions about data models, and so are going to provide more accurate PSD estimates.

I know there are many ways to calculate the PSD but this does not what I am interested in. Let's say I have the Ideal PSD and the Ideal Fourier transform.

The reason there are so many different ways to calculate the PSD is because we are attempting to estimate the true PSD from a single finite length realization of a random process. Even if you had the true Fourier transform of a single realization of a random process, you could not get a PSD. You would need to have the true Fourier transform of all possible realizations (or at least enough to sufficiently sample the probability space such that you could consider your collection to be approximately an ensemble), take the magnitude squared of all these true Fourier transforms, and then average them together. However, it is very rare that we have an ensemble of data in practice, so we resort to many different methods to approximate the true PSD from a single, finite length realization. If our model is correct, we can get very close to the true PSD in specific cases.

such a nice answer! Yes, the core of the problem is "let's say I have the ideal Fourier transform": That thing doesn't exist, since in this universe, you'll see at most one realization of the signal (and that, usually also windowed to a short duration).
